# Setup ActiveMQ as a service

Tags: configuration

I get an error when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/activemq setup /etc/default/activemq`. I'm trying to setup ActiveMQ as a service.

Error:

```
/etc/init.d/activemq: command not found
```

Comment: Can you provide the instructions you're using to set this up?

Answer (score 4):

Install `activemq` :

```
sudo apt-get install activemq
```